# npm install could not resolve packages. What does this mean?

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules

can someone translate to me meaning of this message. I'm not sure what causes here

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.3.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.2.7" from @angular/material@14.2.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.1.0" from ng-zorro-antd@14.3.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/ng-zorro-antd
npm ERR!       ng-zorro-antd@"^14.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   18 more (@angular/forms, @angular/google-maps, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@8.2.14
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0 || ^8.0.0" from @agm/core@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!     @agm/core@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-30T10_27_23_508Z-eresolve-report.txt

i've tried delete @agm/core and it worked well but i need this package

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that @agm/core version 1.1.0 requires a version of @angular/common that is conflicting with the version specified in your project.

The error you're encountering suggests a dependency conflict in your project,
specifically related to the versions of Angular packages and their dependencies.

Remember to backup your project or use version control before making significant changes to your dependencies.
Try this:
npm install --force
npm install --legacy-peer-deps